# Displaying Labels on D3.js Pie Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to display labels on my simple D3.js pie chart with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS:

```
(function(d3) {

    var last_login_today = <?php echo json_encode($last_login_today_count); ?>;
    var last_login_before_today = <?php echo json_encode($did_not_login_today_count); ?>;       

    'use strict';

    var dataset = [
      { label: 'Logged in Today', count: last_login_today }, 
      { label: 'Logged in Before Today', count: last_login_before_today }
    ];

    var width = 360;
    var height = 360;
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20b();

    var svg = d3.select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + 
        ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
      .sort(null);

    var path = svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
        return color(d.data.label);
      });

  })(window.d3);
```

The chart itself is populating correctly but the labels "Logged in Today" and "Logged in Before Today" are not displaying.

Comment: You don't seem to be adding any labels in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with this, labels on pies are a pain when doing them dynamically due to unknown string lengths.

I use this to find the angle point, so I can put it left/right

```
            function midAngle(d) {
                return d.startAngle + ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2);
            }
```

And you'll need this

```
                var labels = svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "labels")
                                .selectAll("text")
                                    .data(pie(dataset))
                                    .enter()
                                    .append("text")
                                        .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                            this._current = this._current || d;
                                            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                                            var d2 = interpolate(0);
                                            var pos = arc.centroid(d2);
                                            pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1.2 : -1.2));
                                            return "translate(" + pos + ")";
                                        })
                                        .attr("dy", ".35em")
                                        .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                        .text(function (d) {
                                            return d.data.Label;
                                        });
```